# Will dynamically generated content via Javascript hurt SEO

Tags: javascript, jquery, seo, search-engine

This is what I would like to do. I would like to load content dynamically.

Everything except the actual content will be rendered by javascript. I will place all the required information in a javascript variable or array at the bottom of the page. Then I will use javascript to place the content in the designated area.

These are the types of things I would like javascript to render:

- Login menu
- Header and logo info
- Side bar info
- Footer info
- Dialog popups
- Ads

All of the MEAT content will not be rendered by javascript. I will use the backend server to put the content in html. My logic is that more of the real content will be in HTML and all the other things will be rendered by javascript. Will this help or hurt SEO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this will hurt SEO.  You want to have all your links/menus/navigation to be accessible by the SEO bots otherwise your site will not be indexed properly.  What exactly is it you're trying to accomplish here?  I'm sure there are plenty of ways to accomplish what you're trying to do without hurting SEO.

Comment: My resoning is: if google sees only the real content and not the other stuff it will increase my SEO ratings. Will it help if I use javascript and submit an xml sitemap to google?

Comment: It will help but your site will look like it has no cross-linking which is a big part of SEO.  Just put this information in DIV's at the bottom of your page and position them with CSS in the correct location.  And make sure you highlight the important content using Header tags, etc.  I would be afraid you'll just end up making things worse by using this method.