# JQuery Document Ready actions read by crawlers?

Tags: jquery, seo

if I have HTML that is generated and put into the body by jQuerys document.ready will google and other crawlers see this HTML in the body or will it not be counted?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will dynamicaly generated content via Javascript hurt SEO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917173/will-dynamicaly-generated-content-via-javascript-hurt-seo)

Comment: Depends. Some crawlers are smart some are not. Some crash on javascript, some ignore it. If you ask will crawler X parse this _specific_ block on js correctly then that's different.

Comment: Thanks for dupe notice. I voted up both answers but accepted Geertvd as it was posted slightly earlier and had a good link to follow. Niklas's answer was still good as well none the less. Thanks to all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this won't be crawled by the bots. the crawlers crawl your html not the rendered dom

here is a good description about this topic:
http://www.searchenginejournal.com/seo-for-ajax/19138/

Answer (score 1):

No. Crawlers won't take into account any of the document changes you may do with JavaScript, on DOM ready or otherwise. They crawl the source code of the page, not the rendered DOM.

As such, when developing sites that use JavaScript to manipulate the page it always wise to keep a `noscript` fallback for users who may not have JavaScript and for crawlers so that they can get the contents of the page as well.